# How to get the CurrentPrincipal Identity on ASP.Net Core 2 Web Application?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, razor-pages

I created a **Azure AD B2C Tenant** to use with an **Azure Function**. I used this and it is working:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Now I am trying to get the User logged in, with this same call this in **ASP Net Core 2** Web Site Razor Page **Index.cshtml.cs**

```
    public void OnGet()
    {
        var isAuth = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        ClaimsPrincipal cp = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    }
```

But 
Thread.CurrentPrincipal is returning null on ASP Net Core 2

In **ConfigureServices** method on **Startup.cs** I added

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        //services.AddAuthentication();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Audience = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"];
            //options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            //{
            //    OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
            //};
            var authorityBase = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{0}/", "empresateste123.onmicrosoft.com"/*Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Tenant"]*/);

            options.Authority = string.Format("{0}{1}/v2.0/", authorityBase, "B2C_1_policysignin " /*Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Policy"]*/);

        });

    }
```

In **Configure** method on **Startup.cs** I added

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

When I publish and go to the URL, this Exception happens on that line:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

If I use

```
    public void OnGet()
    {
        //var isAuth = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        //ClaimsPrincipal cp = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

        var u = this.User;
        var uc = u.Claims.ToList();
    }
```

now it comes, but the Claims.Count = 0, no user information

**What else do I need to add to make it work?**

Comment: Adding Authentication and Authorization with Azure AD B2C https://codemilltech.com/adding-authentication-and-authorization-with-azure-ad-b2c/

Comment: `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is not intended for web-applications like that, see here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx

Comment: To confirm, is this a Razor-Pages project? Where exactly are you putting the call to `CurrentPrincipal`?

Comment: Yes, it is a Razor Pages. I have a Azure Function and a ASP Net Razor Pages, and need to Authenticate the user.

Answer (score 6):

Use `PageModel.User` which returns a `ClaimsPrincipal` object that represents the current *web-application user*. `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` should not be used to get the current web-application user because `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` concerns thread security managed by .NET (and possibly the Operating System).

ASP.NET, all the way back from its early days in 2001 (ab)used this feature of .NET by overwriting `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` with the current ASP.NET "User" - this had practical benefits when it's used in the context of Identity Impersonation with Windows Authentication, allowing web-applications to access security-restricted files, network resources and operating-system features when it would otherwise be unable to.

This article from 2004 gives a good explanation (ignore the references to the now obsolete `FormsAuthentication` module): https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx - the article also explains why `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` may be `null`, for example when application code is called before `HttpApplication.OnThreadEnter()` (which sets the `CurrentPrincipal` property) is called.

I'm not too familiar with the lifecycle of Razor-Pages (a new feature in ASP.NET Core since late 2017) or how the security system changes in an Azure Functions and Azure AppService (f.k.a. Azure Websites) context.

In any event, the fix is to always use the `User` property in ASP.NET instead of `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.

- In ASP.NET Web Forms, use `System.Web.HttpContext::User` (or `System.Web.UI.Page::User`)
- In ASP.NET MVC, use `System.Web.Mvc.Controller::User`

  - ASP.NET MVC (when using `.aspx` Views) can use `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage::User`
  - ASP.NET MVC using Razor Views can access `@this.User` (or just `@User`) directly in Razor code (inherited from `System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase::User`)
- In ASP.NET Core MVC, use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase::User` inside an Action.
- In ASP.NET Razor-Pages, use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageModel::User`.

Comment: Excellent answer. Can you add to the answer the ideal way to get the User on Azure Functions (v1) and (v2)?

Comment: I put the User, now it comes, but the Claims.Count = 0, no user information

Comment: @Tony What is the exact call-site where you're using the `.User` property? Please post more actual code to your question.

Comment: @Dai, Thanks for the answer. And what if we want to acquire the current user (principal) in any lower tiers, where we do not have access to `ControllerBase`?

Comment: @Tohid Outside of `ControllerBase` then you should pass the `ClaimsPrincipal` as a parameter or injected dependency to any other code. There is no `HttpContext.Current` object available either.

Comment: @Dai- Thx again. found a good implementation, as you said, here: https://davidpine.net/blog/principal-architecture-changes/